# Программа не видит python2.4

Tags: python, makefile

При выполнении команды `./configure` программа не видит python2.4.

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for libnet_build_tcp in -lnet... yes
checking for pcap_open_live in -lpcap... yes
checking for pcre_compile in -lpcre... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for tx80211_txpacket in -lorcon... yes
checking for MD5_Init in -lssl... no
configure: openssl required for full WEP key generation
checking for PyString_FromString in -lpython2.4... no
configure: Python2.4 required
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking libnet.h usability... yes
checking libnet.h presence... yes
checking for libnet.h... yes
checking pcap.h usability... yes
checking pcap.h presence... yes
checking for pcap.h... yes
checking tx80211.h usability... yes
checking tx80211.h presence... yes
checking for tx80211.h... yes
checking tx80211_packet.h usability... yes
checking tx80211_packet.h presence... yes
checking for tx80211_packet.h... yes
checking openssl/md5.h usability... yes
checking openssl/md5.h presence... yes
checking for openssl/md5.h... yes
checking python2.4/Python.h usability... yes
checking python2.4/Python.h presence... yes
checking for python2.4/Python.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for vprintf... yes
checking for _doprnt... no
checking for inet_ntoa... yes
checking for strtol... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

Пробовал и не помогло:
Установил пакет:

```
apt install python-dev
```

Пробовал заменять ссылку, т.к. стоял python3

```
rm /usr/bin/python

ln -s /usr/bin/python2.4 /usr/bin/python
```

Также проверил какая версия используется по умолчанию:

```
python -V
Python 2.4
```

Comment: Если программа НАСТОЛЬКО старая, то вряд ли вы её соберёте без полного переписывания кода

Comment: я ищу программу `airpwn`. Это версия 2.4. Также нашел версию airpwn-ng, но с ней тоже пока что ничего не выходит. Буду рад, если кто-то поделится по этому поводу информацией.